# Aligning multiple images

Tags: html, css, image

I am a beginner in web coding, so I started making something like an exercise to see what I can do.

I have tried to align 5 images, and I have been searching anywhere on the web until now when I find out that all I found was very complicated for me now, due to limited knowledge.

```css
#poze {align:"center"}
```

```html
<div id="poze">
  <img src="rsz_1rsz_2000px-color_icon_greensvg.png" alt="green" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />
  <img src="rsz_rsz_2000px-color_icon_bluesvg.png" alt="blue" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />
  <img src="rsz_rsz_2000px-color_icon_yellowsvg.png" alt="yellow" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />
  <img src="rsz_1rsz_2000px-color_icon_redsvg.png" alt="red" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />
  <img src="rsz_1rsz_2000px-color_icon_purplesvg.png" alt="purple" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />
</div>
```

Anything I tried, even the complicated things, didn't work. Is there any possible way to do it only in HTML , without CSS? Or if CSS is needed, is there any simple method?

Comment: Align horizontally or vertically? Or both?

Comment: i want to align them horrizontaly. like, all of them on a line.

Comment: Can you use google to find images, like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Emblem-important-green.svg/200px-Emblem-important-green.svg.png

Comment: just so we understand each other, if you imagine a vertical line stretching from the top to the bottom of each image, you want the middle points of all those imaginary lines to be in a straight horizontal line, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
#poze {
 text-align: center;
}
#poze img {
 padding: 3px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="poze">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32" alt="green" />
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/48/48" alt="blue" />
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/16" alt="yellow" />
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/16/64" alt="red" />
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/32/32" alt="purple" />
</div>
```

This works because `img` elements are `display: inline;` by default.

See Mozilla's excellent CSS documentation for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: [`<img>` are `display: inline`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/#post-8062) by default, they are born that way.

Comment: sorry, yes. that's what i meant to type while thinking something else. i'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

Don't use inline styles.

apply `margin:auto` to `#poze` and a fixed `width` (choose the value that fits you better)

```css
#poze {
  width: 580px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px red dashed
}
img {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="poze">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="green" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="blue" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="yellow" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="red" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="purple" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this [**CSS ruleset**](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) for centering horizontally and vertically `#poze` it never fails (well almost never):

```
#poze {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

### SNIPPET

```css
#poze {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="poze">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/25x75/000/fff?text=1" alt="green" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />

  <img src="http://placehold.it/25x75/00f/fc0?text=2" alt="blue" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />

  <img src="http://placehold.it/25x75/0e0/fa6?text=3" alt="yellow" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />

  <img src="http://placehold.it/25x75/0bb/0ff?text=4" alt="red" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />

  <img src="http://placehold.it/25x75/fff/000?text=5" alt="purple" style="padding:3px;border:3px solid black;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use the CSS3 FlexBox module :

**HTML:**

```
<div id="poze">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/100/" alt="img1" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/100" alt="img2" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/100" alt="img3" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/100" alt="img4" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/100" alt="img5" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#poze{
    display:flex;
}

img{
    margin:2px;
}
```

See JSFiddle demo link : https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/zz1nyg7p/